# PHP cURL POST Request won't send?

Tags: php, mysql, curl, post

I'm trying to update a mySQL database with cURL and PHP, but the values that are supposed to be sent by the post aren't inserted into the database. I don't get any errors and cURL is enabled according to phpinfo(). Here is my script:

```
<?php

  $data = [
    'email' => 'jsnow@got.com',
    'token' => '58938539'
  ];

$string = http_build_query($data);
$ch = curl_init("http://www.econcentre.com/receiver.php");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

And here's the receiver script:

```
<?php
   require 'includes/db.php';  // Database connection. Connects with no errors raised

   if(isset($_POST['email']) AND isset($_POST['token'])) {
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $token = $_POST['token'];

     $q = "INSERT INTO reset_tokens(email, token)";
     $q .= " VALUES(?, ?)";
     $stmt = $pdo->prepare($q);
     $test = $stmt->execute([$email, $token]);
 }

?>
```

Comment: Did you check curl errors after `exec()` ? `if (curl_errno($ch)) { echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch); }`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added your if statement but it didn't echo an error.

Comment: So, did you `var_dump($_POST)` in your receiver script, before `isset()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing HTTP Auth for *http://www.econcentre.com/receiver.php*.

You should include the HTTP Auth in the cURL request:

```
<?php

$data = [
    'email' => 'jsnow@got.com',
    'token' => '58938539'
];
$username = "auth-user";
$password = "auth-pwd";

$string = http_build_query($data);
$ch = curl_init("http://www.econcentre.com/receiver.php");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```